# How to make cxf jax-rs response.readEntity as generic

Tags: java, generics, jax-rs, cxf

The below code is working fine. I need to reuse this methods for all requests. How to make it as generics?

```
public class ApiResponse {

}


public class QuoteRespWrapper extends ApiResponse{
    private String responseType;
    private QuoteRespValue responseValue;
}


public class PolicyRespWrapper extends ApiResponse{
    private String responseType;
    private PolicyRespValue responseValue;
}



public QuoteRespWrapper callService(String endPoint, String payload, Class<? extends ApiResponse> respClass) throws Exception {
    private static List<JacksonJsonProvider> providerList = singletonList(JacksonConfig.jacksonJsonProvider());
    String userName="user1";
    String password="password1";
    WebClient client = WebClient.create(endPoint, providerList, userName, password, null);
    Response webClientresponse = client.post(payload);
    QuoteRespWrapper strResponse = webClientresponse.readEntity(QuoteRespWrapper.class);
    return strResponse;
}
```

I need to modify the below line based on class type. It can be any subclass of ApiResponse (QuoteRespWrapper,PolicyRespWrapper,....). I need to pass 
argument .class dynamically to get the response.

QuoteRespWrapper strResponse = webClientresponse.readEntity(QuoteRespWrapper.class);

Comment: respClass = webClientresponse.readEntity(respClass.class);. We can't pass respClass.class, compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toString` to produce the class name output as expected (e.g. `class java.lang.String`):

```
webClientresponse.readEntity(respClass.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ApiResponse callService(String endPoint, String payload, Class<? extends ApiResponse> respClass) throws Exception {
    private static List<JacksonJsonProvider> providerList = singletonList(JacksonConfig.jacksonJsonProvider());
    String userName="user1";
    String password="password1";
    WebClient client = WebClient.create(endPoint, providerList, userName, password, null);
    Response webClientresponse = client.post(payload);
    ApiResponse strResponse = (ApiResponse) webClientresponse.readEntity(respClass);
    return strResponse;
}
```

The above code fulfilled my need.